# why django load actually the template contents?

Tags: django, django-templates

after runsrever my browser show this:**

```
> {% set enabled_scopes_class = 'scopes-' +
> '%s'|format(settings.ALL_SCOPE_ENABLED) + '-' +
> '%s'|format(settings.UNANSWERED_SCOPE_ENABLED) + '-' +
> '%s'|format((request.user.is_authenticated() and
> settings.FOLLOWED_SCOPE_ENABLED)) %} {# Some or all contents of this
> div may be dropped over the search bar via negative margins, to make
> sure that the search bar can occupy 100% of the content width. Search
> bar may have padding on the left and right to accomodate the buttons.
> `#}{# three buttons below are in the opposite order because they are
> floated at the right #}`
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see the raw code when rendering the template, is that statements must be on a single line, both tags and comments.

For the multiline comments, you can use the `comment` tag:

```
{% comment %}
Some or all contents of this
div may be dropped over the search bar via negative margins, to make
sure that the search bar can occupy 100% of the content width. Search
bar may have padding on the left and right to accomodate the buttons.
three buttons below are in the opposite order because they are
floated at the right
{% endcomment %}
```

As for your `set` statement: I don't know about any `set` statement (is it a third-party tag?), but the template language is by design not nearly as powerful as Python code. The use of parentheses to group statements is not permitted, and you can't call functions with arguments in the same way you can do it in python. You also cannot concatenate values with `+` and `format` is not a defined template filter. I'd suggest you read up on templates [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

More advanced logic, like what you are trying to do here, should be done in the view function, and passed on to the context of the template.

Comment: the probllem isnt at multiline comments ! when i delete all comment it show template content again ! is this problem in my call in parent template or in this template ?
this is a part of base template (browser shows secondary_header.html ) : 
  {% include "custom_header.html" %}
        {% if settings.CUSTOM_HEADER != '' %}
        <div id="custom-header">
            {{settings.CUSTOM_HEADER}}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% include "widgets/header.html" %} {# Logo, user tool navigation and meta navitation #}
        {% include "widgets/secondary_header.html"  %}

Comment: @bluebird7 And what about the `set` tag? Is the complete tag (from `{%` to `%}`) on a single line?

Comment: yes i write the block in 1 line its done ! thanks alot ! bot after that browser dont show any think ... i dont have an idea try to find the problem !!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not render your template

try something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):

    return render(request, 'path/template.html', {})
```

Comment: no i do that ........!i think  with out render the browser dont raise any thing !!!